# Specific WolframAlpha query? [Python]

Tags: python, wolframalpha

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1844.8*x%2By%2B0.0084063099220244904*z%3D1844.8,+2538510.9599999995*x%5E2%2B0.38081996307262644*z%5E2%2B2*188.9275870870740*x*z%3D2538510.9599999995,+22.800000000000001*x-0.20000000000000001*y%2B0.54888787955652119*z%3D5](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1844.8*x%2By%2B0.0084063099220244904*z%3D1844.8,%202538510.9599999995*x%5E2%2B0.38081996307262644*z%5E2%2B2*188.9275870870740*x*z%3D2538510.9599999995,%2022.800000000000001*x-0.20000000000000001*y%2B0.54888787955652119*z%3D5)

I need to make this query in Python, I have tried:

```
import wolframalpha
app_id='XXXXXXX'
client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
res = client.query('i=1844.8*x%2By%2B0.0084063099220244904*z%3D1844.8,+2538510.9599999995*x%5E2%2B0.38081996307262644*z%5E2%2B2*188.9275870870740*x*z%3D2538510.9599999995,+22.800000000000001*x-0.20000000000000001*y%2B0.54888787955652119*z%3D5')
for pod in res.pods:
  for sub in pod.subpods:
    print(sub.text)
```

But it wasn´t successful. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you sure this library expects [url-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) string? I'd expect that basic string form is expected.

Comment: Thank you @ŁukaszRogalski but I have another error now, `AttributeError: text` do you know what is the reason? :S